# What is an error analyzing app version when distributing from Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode

I want to distribute app, but I received the error. I don't know the cause.

I use Xcode Version 13.0 (13A233)

An error was Encountered:

```
 Error Analyzing App Version (Build number request failed with error: BuildsService: ResponseErrors (1): Error status: 403, code: FORBIDDEN_ERROR, title: 'This request is forbidden for security reasons', detail: 'The API key in use does not allow this request', id: 65cc1b85-e0d4-4f86-8bab-e72d7149c9cc)
```

[image]

Comment: Are you using an appstore-connect API key in order to upload the app? The error message clearly states the API key is not authorised to perform that action. Either that or mabye your appstore connect account doesn't have the right permissions

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin 
Thank you so much. I didn't know what the 'API Key' the error was talking about.
As you said, when I checked the 'app Store Connect API', there was no key. So I created a key. But still that error still appears. Do I have to register that key somewhere?

Comment: you may not need an API key. I asked first if you were trying to use one, as the error indicates you are. You only need an API key for certain command line tasks, or if your account is using 2 factor authentication. If any of those are true, you need to create an API key and then make use of it however it in the upload process. Instead of your username / password you need to supply the api key. The other issue might be that your appstore connect account doesn't have permissions to manage apps. It would also be helpful if you detailed how you are actually trying to upload it as there are many

Comment: @juh2, did you solve it?

Comment: Temporary Apple outage. Issue automatically resolved now.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I fixed this issue by removing every Apple ID in Xcode except the one that has the developer role in App Store Connect for the app I was trying to validate / distribute. I assume Xcode was trying to use the wrong account at some point in the process.

Comment: We was uploading many times succesfully and suddenly this error came up. Very strange that xcode was using the second

Comment: Removing the `Customer Support User` will be useful

Comment: I had two accounts in XCode accounts WORK and PERSONAL app store accounts. I had used my icloud email address e.g. first.last@me.com as ADMIN on my PERSONAL app store account to release my own apps. But I had used my personal phone as Testflight user on my WORK account so  first.last@me.com also appeared in USERS for my WORK app store account but with ROLE: Customer Service. Quick fix remove the PERSONAL account in Xcode accounts. OR in app store connect log into WORK account and remove the test flight Customer Support user with email first.last@me.com Xcode using wrong ac should use admin one

Comment: I had a bunch of accounts in there, one which had been reclaimed by recently joining the Apple Business program and claiming our company's domain when implementing SSO. This broke some of the accounts. Needed to be removed and added again.

Answer (score 93):

Might be temporary Apple outage. See:
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/705599

Here's a workaround:

1. Organizer -> Distribute App -> App Store Connect -> Export -> NOW DISABLE WIFI / INTERNET (else will fail) -> Exported .ipa
2. Now use Transporter App -> Login to same account -> Add .ipa -> Upload works !

Transporter can be downloaded here:
https://apps.apple.com/app/transporter/id1450874784

Comment: It works for me right now. I didn’t do anything special, I just tried to validate & upload again.

Comment: Earlier I thought it was an issue with IPA and created 15 IPA for the same still it is not working!

Comment: It works after 3-4 times of same process!

Comment: I also got the same error today. You can try via Transporter

Comment: I edited my answer, and added a workaround.

Comment: When you click the Export radio button, disable Wifi, THEN click Next, enable Wifi after you get to the options, then click Next again, then signing options, Next, Export.

Comment: @John i was able to export without enabling wifi until I got the .ipa.

Comment: Transporter is always the steadiest

Comment: Restarting my machine fixed the issue.

Comment: @DavidKyslenko Oddly, I had to do those exact steps. If I did not re-enable Wifi, it failed. I tried (and failed) multiple times, so I figured I'd post here in case anyone else had the same issue. Thanks for your answer it was a big help (I neglected to add that before).

Answer (score 10):

I was able to resolve it by attempting to submit an older uploaded version and then canceling as soon as that step was completed. Then I tried to upload the new version again, surprisingly it passed that check ✅. If the process fails then try to restart the mac.

Comment: Make sure to select an older version that has already been submitted to and published on the AppStore, selecting versions that were only on TestFlight failed for me.

Comment: I tried this and it failed. But then I rebooted my Mac and it worked... 

Comment: I assume that there is a problem on Apple's side. Check it out:

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/705599#705599021

Comment: Using an older build to pass the version check worked for me, lol, nice job Apple. Thanks for the great answer!

Answer (score 5):

Today I've faced the same problem. I tried to remove all previous versions. Then after a while I archived new version and this step successfully passed. It seems that was a problem on Apple side.
[Problem at apple dev forum](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/705599)

Don't try to remove certificates and etc. It would bring more problems.

Comment: I am also facing same problem since morning. What you did to solve problem?

Answer (score 3):

I got "Error Analyzing App Version" without any additional details. I just deleted the archive and create it again and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

Just go to xcode preferences->accounts->Download manual profiles and try uploading again it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

I am also facing the same issue from last few hours, it seemed like this issue is arising form Apple side, so doing any changes with certificates or bundle id etc may make it worst to get resolved, thought to wait if Apple respond on this [thread](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/705599)

Solved it through Changing the app version from 1.0.0 to 1.0 on Xcode. still this is not guaranteed solution cause its not working on the other Mac.

Answer (score 1):

Someone posted the following workaround on Apple's Developer Forums:

> WORKING BYPASS: While Apple's Hardcore Software engineers drink coffee and figure this bug out!
> Organizer -> Distribute App -> App Store Connect -> Export -> NOW DISABLE WIFI / INTERNET (else will fail) -> Exported .ipa
> Now use Transporter App -> Login to same account -> Add .ipa -> Upload works !
> Transporter Can be downloaded from AppStore

I managed to upload my app to TestFlight this way.

See https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/705599?answerId=712953022#712953022

Answer (score 1):

I had the same message without any description error message like below. I was trying to upload the build to Testflight and encountered this issue.

[image]

My solution is only to do with the versioning of the XCode. As I was using new `Version` number with a random `Build` number. For example `Version` I set as 1.2.0 and `Build` 17, even though I haven't uploaded `Build` 1 for `Version` 1.2.0.

After setting up `Version` 1.2 and `Build` 1, everything worked.

Comment: same happened to me but my build versions were correct. Display name was missing because when I set display name by myself (before it was showing as a placeholder) my build successfully uploaded

Comment: There are many issues related to this error, seems like the error is on Apple's side. Even a couple of hours later again I got the same error. 10/05/2022 it didn't work and I tried 11/05/2022 with the same configuration and it worked. So sometimes its better to wait (if you have time) before making huge changes to your project configurations.

Comment: Thank you! This was the issue for me. I had my version as (0.0.4-alpha) and Build 1, so I removed "alpha" from it (0.0.4) and Build 1 and fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I changed my Apple id password and got this error.
I checked Xcode -> Preference -> Accounts and noticed that session has expired.
I re-logged in and got the same error again.
And I just restarted my Mac and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to recreate the App Store distribution certificate and then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

In Flutter, I solved it by changing the `$(MARKETING_VERSION)` to `$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME)` for `CFBundleShortVersionString` key in the `Info.plist` file

```
<key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
<string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME)</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had this and fixed it by signing out of Apple in XCode and then signing back in.

XCode > Preferences > Accounts > Minus (-) button at the bottom left, then plus (+) button and signed back in. Took 15secs once I tried it.

Answer (score 0):

I encounter this issue suddently. I had uploaded a binary with build 0 yesterday. Then try to upload a binary with build 2 and meet 'Error Analyzing App Version'.

Instead of upload directly, I export the binary and upload it with 'Transporter' app and everything works. So strange.

Answer (score 0):

In my case my apple certificate in my keychain was expired so after creating new certificate and deleting previous certificate it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Go to Runner :
Then Go to Signing & capabilities:

Check All - Debug - Release - Profile

Team , Bundle Identifier and others information are same or Not . if not same kindly fix it . Mainly this is causing the Error.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to fix this by adding a key to Info.plist: `Bundle version string (short)`, set to `$(MARKETING_VERSION)`.

Answer (score -1):

Don't need to do anything special. As strange as it sounds, the error does not occur if you upload during the first few minutes after the top of each hour.

Answer (score -4):

i just give the version number a bump, from .42 to .43,

then it all fine.
still not sure the root cause of the problem.